# How to add random values based on values from two rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create mock data with random values. I have three replicates for each combination (e.g. s1='1' && s2='a'). For each one of these, I want to add a random integer. I'll manually change the range of the `randint()` for each combination of `s1` & `s2` because I don't know how to do it programmatically. A recommendation would be appreciated but it's not the focus of my question.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import random 

s1 = pd.Series(['1', '3', '5', '7', '9'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['s1', 's2', 's3'])
df['s1'] =  s1.repeat(9)
s2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df['s2'] = np.tile(s2, len(df)//len(s2))

#my attempt
for i in df:
    if ['s1']=='3' and ['s2']=='b':
        density['s2'] = density['s3'].concat(random.randint(28,32))
```

Comment: What is your expected output based on the sample data?

Comment: Apologies, Chris. I missed this comment. I'll include the expected output next time I ask a question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary of bounds per combination and `groupby.transform`:

```
import numpy as np

bounds = {('1', 'a'): (10, 20), ('1', 'b'): (100, 200)}

def rnd(g):
    a,b = bounds.get(g.name, (0,2))
    return np.random.randint(a, b, size=len(g))
    
df['s3'] = df.groupby(['s1', 's2'])['s1']. transform(rnd)
```

Example:

```
  s1 s2   s3
0  1  a   15
0  1  b  127
0  1  c    0
0  1  a   16
0  1  b  170
0  1  c    1
0  1  a   12
0  1  b  174
0  1  c    0
1  3  a    0
1  3  b    0
1  3  c    0
1  3  a    1
1  3  b    1
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @mozway. I just have two questions:
How would I modify it to work with all possible combinations? 1xa, 1xb, 1xc, 3xa, 3xb, 3xc...
Also, why are values showing in s1 for 3?

Comment: @DanielGonzález 1- add all wanted combinations in the dictionary (or explain a programmatic rule). 2- because there are default bounds (0,2) in case a combination of not defined in the dictionary

Comment: I appreciate it! I won't be able to try it until the weekend as this is a separate project, but will test it as soon as I'm able to. Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to thank you again. I tried it during the weekend and it worked perfectly. Thanks for helping me with it @mozway!